# R - put space at word begins with capital letter, for full column

Tags: r

i am having a column from XLSX imported to R, where each row is having a sentence without space, but words begins with Capital letters. tried to use

```
gsub("([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]][[:lower:]])", "\\1 \\2", x)
```

but this is working, if i start converting each row,

**Example**

```
1 HowDoYouWorkOnThis
2 ThisIsGreatExample
3 ProgrammingIsGood
```

**Expected is**

```
1 How Do You Work On This
2 This Is Great Example
3 Programming Is Good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
s <- c("HowDoYouWorkOnThis", "ThisIsGreatExample", "ProgrammingIsGood");

sapply(s, function(x) trimws(gsub("([A-Z])", " \\1", x)))
#       HowDoYouWorkOnThis        ThisIsGreatExample         ProgrammingIsGood
#"How Do You Work On This"   "This Is Great Example"     "Programming Is Good"
```

Or using `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr);
trimws(str_replace_all(s, "([A-Z])", " \\1"));
#[1] "How Do You Work On This" "This Is Great Example"
#[3] "Programming Is Good"
```

Comment: You're very welcome @PraveenMKulkarni; please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.